# Make NavigationBar Title same as table cell chosen in previous view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, ios5

I am trying to learn iPhone development as I've read many others on here are also saying. And Ive searched through about 20 pages of previous threads but couldn't quite find one that is what I need. I have a TableViewController as my root view that is inside a NavigationController. I have a grouped table with 2 cells inside the TableViewController and was wanting the text of which ever cell was selected to become the title of the next view's NavigationBar. I am using Xcode 4.3 and storyboards. Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the  `tableview:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, I assume that you are creating and pushing your next view controller. You also must be having an Array (or some data source) which populates the text in the Tableview. So get the current cell's text by using indexpath.row. Set this text to:

```
nextViewController.title = cellText;
```

So when you push this view controller, it'll have the title of the cell selected.

Comment: Well I actually use storyboards so I just control+click+drag to new view to set up the view transitions. I also just used interface builder to drag a table onto view and graphically populated table cells. ??? LOL

Answer (score 1):

> try below it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method will help you

```
detailViewController.title = [[[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];
```